# boundedness in a locally convex space

Tags: functional-analysis

From Conway, A course in functional analysis, page 107. Problem 6.

Let $X$ be a locally compact space and give $C_b(X)$ the strict topology $\beta$ defined by the seminorms $p_\phi(f)= ||\phi f||_\infty$ for every $\phi \in C_0(X)$. Show that a subset of $C_b(X)$ is $\beta$ - bounded if and only if it is norm bounded.

My attempt: suppose B is a norm bounded set. there is $M>0$ such that for every $f\in B$ , $$||f||<M \Rightarrow p_\phi(f)=\sup |\phi(x)f(x)|< ||\phi||_\infty M ~~~(\phi \in C_0(X))$$
which show that $B$ is $\beta$ - bounded.

Conversely, suppose $B$ is $\beta$ - bounded. for every $\phi \in C_0(X)$, there is $t_\phi>0$ such that $B\subset t_\phi\{g\in C_b(X) ; ~~p_\phi(g)<1\}$. but I get stuck. I can not show that $B$ is  norm bounded.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I believe it goes. You can work out an omitted detail or two. The linear map $T_f: C_0(X)\to C_0(X)$ defined by $\phi\mapsto \phi f$ is bounded and $||T_f||\le ||f||_\infty$. By taking $\phi$ to be a suitable bump function (or if necessary a sequence of bump functions), $||T_f||=||f||_\infty$. By ''bump" is meant that $\phi$ is of compact support, $\phi\equiv 1$ on a compact subset, $0\le\phi\le 1$ on $X$. For the existence of such functions on locally compact spaces see Theo.2.12 in Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*.

$B$ is $\beta$-bounded implies that $p_\phi$ is bounded on $B$ for each $\phi\in C_0(X)$, i.e. $||\phi f||_\infty \le M_\phi$ for all $f\in B$, i.e. $||T_f\phi||_\infty\le M_\phi$ for all $f\in B$.

Now use the uniform boundedness theorem to conclude that $||f||_\infty=||T_f||\le M$ for all $f\in B$.